# Can't store too lengthy int type

Tags: c++

Consider the problem:

```
It can be shown that for some powers of two in decimal format like:
2^9 = 512
2^89 = 618,970,019,642,690,137,449,562,112
```

The results end in a string consisting of 1s and 2s. In fact, it can be proven that for every integer R, there
exists a power of 2 such that 2K where K > 0 has a string of only 1s and 2s in its last R digits.

It can be shown clearly in the table below:

```
R Smallest K 2^K
1 1 2
2 9 512
3 89 ...112
4 89 ...2112
```

Using this technique, what then is the sum of all the smallest K values for 1 <= R <= 10? 
    Proposed sol:
    Now this problem ain't that difficult to solve. You can simply do
    int temp = power(2, int)
and then if you can get the length of the temp then multiply it with

```
(100^len)-i or (10^len)-i
```

// where i would determine how many last digits you want.

Now this **temp = power(2,int) gets much higher with increasing int that you can't even store it in the int type or even in long int**....
So what would be done. And is there any other solution based on bit strings. I guess that might make this problem easy.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No, I doubt there are any solutions based on "strings of bits". That would be quite inefficient. But there are Bignum Libraries like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) which feature variable types either fixed-size much bigger than int types, or of arbitrary size limited only by memory capacity, plus matching sets of math operations, working similarly to software FPU emulation.

Quoting after [reference](http://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Interface-General.html) with a minor paraphrase.

```
 #include <gmpxx.h>

 int
 main (void)
 {
   mpz_class a, b, c;

   a = 1234;
   b = "-5676739826856836954375492356569366529629568926519085610160816539856926459237598";
   c = a+b;
   cout << "sum is " << c << "\n";
   cout << "absolute value is " << abs(c) << "\n";

   return 0;
 }
```

Thanks to C++ operator overloading, it is much easier to use than ANSI C version.

Comment: Actually I heard this library first time. Can you come up with a simple, illustrative example.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only interested in the the `n` least significant digits of your result, you could try to devise an algorithm that only calculates those. Based on the [standard algorithm for written multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication) you can see that the `n` least significant digits of the product are entirely determined by the `n` least significant digits of the multiplicands. Based on this it should be possible to create an algorithm that calculates as many digits of `R^K` as fit into a `long int`.

The only problem you might run into is that there may be numbers that end in a matching sequence that is longer that a `long int` can hold. In that case you can still resort to calculating additional digits using your own algorithm or a library.

Note that this is basically the same thing that big-number libraries do, only your approach might be more efficient, because you are calculating less digits that you are unlikely to need.

Answer (score 1):

Try GMP, http://gmplib.org/
It can store a number with any size if it fits in the memory.
Altough you might be better off with less brute force approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can store binary strings in std::bitset or in std::vector
[www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/)

I think bitset is your choice.

Using big arithmetic for operations on powers of 2 is not though

Comment: Okay. Just one thing. is there any certain pattern of bit strings that would be followed in this problem.